# Java - solving problems larger than memory limit

Tags: java, algorithm

I was recently pondering the following scenario: suppose you have a huge database and you want to perform some calculations while loading some of its part. It can be the case, that even small part of that database might not fit into Java's heap memory which is quite limited. How do people go about solving these obstacles? How does google perform analysis on Terabytes of data with limited memory space?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Google is using a massive parallel approach to wrangle its data. See [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) for more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to process the data in chunks that do fit into memory and then assemble the results of these chunked computes into a final answer (possibly in multiple stages). A common distributed paradigm for this is Map Reduce: see [here](http://research.google.com/archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) for details on Google's original implementation, and [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) for an open-source implementation.

Comment: Lower limit for Hadoop is a few hundred gigabytes. Otherwise it could be an overkill.

Comment: @Deniz: Absolutely. If you're only a couple of multiples of memory in data size, process the chunks on a single machine with your own code and no heavy-weight framework.

Answer (score 1):

I use a 64-bit JVM with off heap memory such as direct ByteBuffers and memory mapped files.  This way you can have into the TBs of virtual memory while the heap is 1 GB or less.  I have run different applications where the JVM has a virtual memory size 10x larger than physical memory with a modest loss of performance.  If you can use a fast SSD this can help you when your working dataset is larger than your main memory.

Answer (score 0):

You would either have to get more memory and increase your heap size, or if this is not possible, write an algorithm that will only load subsets or your data at a time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Increase your physical memory and/or virtual memory size(s)

2) Use multiple computers with sharding or similar technique

3) Process your data in smaller pieces that do fit in memory

4) Use smarter datastructure choices that use less memory, like bloom filters or tries, if appropriate.

5) You might even be able to compress/decompress data in memory using a compression algorithm.